# music with shell script

Tags: bash, shell

the following command will output a beep sound.

> beep -f 10200 -l 500

I am  curious to know whether someone have a shell script which generates music using the beep command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule #34: [If you can think about it, then someone on the internet has done it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1157670).

[Here's another one.](http://kirrus.co.uk/2010/09/linux-beep-music/)